# Determine the orthogonal projection $\pi_{U}(e_{2})$ of $e_{2}$ onto $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, machine-learning, projective-geometry

I tried to solve the task 3.6.a in the book
[Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf)

**Consider $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with the inner product**

$$\left \langle x,y \right \rangle:=x^{T}\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 2 & -1\\ 
0 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}y.$$

**Furthermore, we define $e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}$ as the standard/canonical basis in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.**

**Determine the orthogonal projection $\pi_{U}(e_{2})$ of $e_{2}$ onto $U=\text{span}[e_{1},e_{3}]$.**

and i hope you forgive if i post the question with the link because it is difficult to write.

[my solutions are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8ThB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\pi_{U}(e_{2})\in U$, we can define $\Lambda = (\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2})\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $\pi_{U}(e_{2})=U\Lambda$. $\pi_{U}(e_{2})$ becomes $\pi_{U}(e_{2})=\lambda_{1}e_{1}+\lambda_{3}e_{3}=[\lambda_{1},0,\lambda_{3}]^{\top}$ expressed in the canonical basis.

By orthogonal projection,

\begin{align*} 
&(\pi_{U}(e_{2})-e_{2}) \perp U\\
\implies &\begin{bmatrix}
\left \langle \pi_{U}(e_{2})-e_{2},e_{1} \right \rangle\\ 
\left \langle \pi_{U}(e_{2})-e_{2},e_{3} \right \rangle
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\implies &\begin{bmatrix}
\left \langle \pi_{U}(e_{2}),e_{1} \right \rangle-\left \langle e_{2},e_{1} \right \rangle\\ 
\left \langle \pi_{U}(e_{2}),e_{3} \right \rangle-\left \langle e_{2},e_{3} \right \rangle
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

We compute the individual components as

$$\left \langle \pi_{U}(e_{2}),e_{1} \right \rangle=\left [ \lambda_{1} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }0\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } \lambda_{3} \right ] \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 2 & -1\\ 
0 &- 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}=2\lambda_{1}.$$

**Source: M. P. Deisenroth, A. A. Faisal.**

Comment: My Solution is (1/2,0,-1/2) i think it is correct?